# Dynamically added html div loses css style

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I am trying to append a html div element with some html in it to another div with class-name `top-sellers` using response from an ajax call.

ajax call response:

```
success : function(response) {
    var top_products_list = response.top_products;
    var new_products_list = response.new_products;

    product_query = '';
    $.each(new_products_list, function(i, item) {
                      product_query = product_query + "<div class='col-md-3 product-div'><section class='panel'><div class='pro-img-box'><img src='" + new_products_list[i][0] + "' alt='/></div><div class='panel-body text-center'><h4><a href='/product/" + new_products_list[i][7] + "/" + new_products_list[i][6] + "' class='pro-title'>" + new_products_list[i][1] + "</a></h4><p class='quantity'>" + new_products_list[i][2] + new_products_list[i][3] + "</p><p class='price'>Rs. " + new_products_list[i][4] + "<span style='padding-left: 5%;text-decoration: line-through;color: #797979;'>Rs. " + new_products_list[i][5] + "</span></p><div><button class='btn btn-success addtocart'>Add To Cart</button><button class='btn btn-success addtofav'><i class='fa fa-heart'></i></button></div></div></section></div>";
    });
    console.log(product_query);
    $('.new-arrivals').html(product_query);
    $('.top-sellers').html(product_query);
},
```

I can see all the data is appended to div. But It loses all the styling after that.
 If i load them without ajax, the div looks like this:

[image]

And if load them with ajax:

[image]

How can i correct that?

EDIT:  Without AJAX Sample Html Div

```
<div class="col-md-3 product-div">
    <section class="panel">
        <div class="pro-img-box">
            <img src="https://c143.pcloud.com/dHZ6pwkZyfUAy7ZzvHjZZMHpBq7Z2ZZV9RZkZnJc8ZeA6MekI4mFjL2dypSEvqH8v2QRjV/friends.jpg" alt=""/>
         </div>
         <div class="panel-body text-center">
             <h4>
                 <a href="#" class="pro-title">Leopard Shirt Dress</a>
             </h4>
             <p class="quantity">200 ml</p>
             <p class="price">Rs. 300.00<span style="padding-left: 5%;text-decoration: line-through;color: #797979;">Rs. 350.00</span></p>
             <div>
                 <button class="btn btn-success addtocart">Add To Cart</button><button class="btn btn-success addtofav"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></button>
             </div>
         </div>
     </section>
 </div>

Ajax response div is in jquery code.
```

Comment: If the HTML structure of the content appended in the AJAX callback matches what is in your first example, then there is no reason why the CSS applied would be any different. You need to inspect the HTML and see what's causing the change. The fact you're loading content through AJAX is not enough by itself to change how CSS is applied.

Comment: you miss some styles selector

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I added the sample div.

Comment: `<img src='" + new_products_list[i][0] + "' alt='/></div><div class='...` should be `<img src='" + new_products_list[i][0] + "' alt=''/></div><div class='...`